# For loop to fill a dataframe by columns does not work

Tags: python, api, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a `for` loop that is inside an objected oriented program in Python.

1. At first the function `get_data` makes an API request to retrieve information of each symbol that are in the list symbols above.
2. Secondly the function `extract_data(self,response,symbol)` have the parameter response that is the result of the API request and the parameter symbol that I use with the debug module to track the for loop.

This `for` loop extracts the data from an API, and finally appends it into a list that called *tickers*.

```
symbols = ["ETHBTC","LTCBTC","BNBBTC","NEOBTC"]

def __init__(self,interval):
    self.interval = interval
    for symbol in symbols:
        ohlc = self.get_data(symbol)
        self.extract_data(ohlc,symbol)


def extract_data(self,response,symbol):

    all_tickers = pd.DataFrame()

    tickers = []
    data = response.json()      

    for item in data:
        open_ = item[1]
        high =  item[2]
        low =  item[3]
        close = item[4]
        volume = float(item[5])
        timestamp = item[6]
        timestamp = timestamp / 1000
        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp=timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        tickers.append({"close":close,"date":date})

    logging.debug("Download {} day prices of ohlc data from {} pair".format(len(tickers),symbol))
    all_tickers = all_tickers.append(pd.DataFrame(tickers))
```

I have tried many times with different structures for making a dataframe that have in each column the price for each asset and the date as index, but at the moment I cannot reach the solution.

Some advice or suggestion, will be very welcome.

Comment: Where is your datareaders code? What is your expected output?

Comment: Please show example output of `response.json() `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few steps - first modify `extract_data` to return a list of tuples of the data you want, including the symbol

```
def extract_data(self,response,symbol):
    tickers = []
    ... 

    for item in data:
        ...
        tickers.append((close, date, symbol))

    ...

    return tickers
```

Then as you loop through your symbols, create a "master" list.

```
data = []
for symbol in symbols:
    ohlc = self.get_data(symbol)
    symb_data = self.extract_data(ohlc,symbol)
    data = data + symb_data
```

Should end up with something like

```
[(45, datetime.date(2017, 12, 23), 'ETHBTC'),
 (46, datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), 'ETHBTC'),
 (47, datetime.date(2017, 12, 23), 'LTCBTC'),
 (48, datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), 'LTCBTC'),
 (49, datetime.date(2017, 12, 23), 'BNBBTC'),
 (50, datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), 'BNBBTC'),
 (51, datetime.date(2017, 12, 23), 'NEOBTC'),
 (52, datetime.date(2017, 12, 24), 'NEOBTC')]
```

And finally create the dataframe and pivot the table

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(data, 
                   columns=["close", "date", "ticker"])
      .pivot(index="date", 
             columns="ticker", 
             values="close"))

print(df)
```

To get

```
ticker      BNBBTC  ETHBTC  LTCBTC  NEOBTC
date                                      
2017-12-23      49      45      47      51
2017-12-24      50      46      48      52
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken Syme! The dataframe was generate as I wanted. I have one more comment, that is the following: I want to work with the dataframe, and need to store an acces to it in an independent object. I mean I need to do some analyis with the dataframe, but the program is in OOP, and I only see the output when I put print inside the program.

Comment: Maybe in this case I don´t need an OOP and can work only with functions, that for my final goal of store the object in a dataframe and work with it is more handly I suppose